# not getting response response = httpclient.execute(request);

Tags: android, httpclient, http-post

```
public class HTTPPoster {
    public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, JSONObject c) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException 
    {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpEntity entity;
        StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString());
        s.setContentEncoding((Header) new BasicHeader(HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET, "application/json"));
        entity = s;
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(request);

        return response;
    }

}
```

This is the code but on **`response = http.client.execute(request)`** doesn't get response. I couldn't find why.

Comment: Sorry Demet I would love to answer your question but you are giving us  not a lot to work with. And that note in the most polite way. Just asking for code is not the best behavior. 

What res

Comment: What is the response that you get? Is it null? Is there an Exception thrown?

Answer (score 3):

You should call the method asynchronously. Then it will work with the same code. 
Add these two lines of code to your project

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

and
make minimum sdk version to 9

Comment: many thanks to you! I found all http request example and all not work. After I add your code, all examples work fine! Why these examples not mention your code?

Comment: @YiFeng you can also use asyncTask feature of android to achieve the same result. Here is a quick link to asyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.     You should call your http request inside the doBackgroundTask function. Doing blocking tasks in main thread is not preferred in android. Blocking tasks should be done in background thread

Answer (score 1):

You can check that if you are getting response from server or not by using following code :

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient1.execute(request);
                    Log.v("response code", response.getStatusLine()
                            .getStatusCode() + "");
```

If you get the value of response code as 200 then you are getting data from server and if the response code value >=300 then you have error at your server side.

Comment: The response is not a `HtppResponse` but a `String`. Or how do you get it to be a `HttpResponse`? Does this depend on the `ResponseHandler`?

Comment: @Peterdk : please see the following question i asked after your comment.The answer i gave is correct .You kindly update your knowledge.See my question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365741/is-httpresponse-string/8365974#8365974

Comment: If you supply a `responsehandler`, the method returns `T`. So there is also a generic method of `execute` available, and in case of the `BasicResponseHandler` it returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to change the return type to `String` by doing these 2 steps

Change

```
public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, JSONObject c) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
```

to

```
public static String doPost(String url, JSONObject c) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
```

**AND**

Change

```
HttpResponse response;
```

to

```
String response;
```

---

Now check the response string? Is it still null?

---

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission issue.

Add this line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your manifest file and rebuild.