# Is HttpResponse String?

Tags: android, httpresponse

I answered the following question :

[not getting response response = httpclient.execute(request);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939122/not-getting-response-response-httpclient-executerequest)

See my answer there.Then I got a comment on my answer from 
 Peterdk

as :

> The response is not a HtppResponse but a String. Or how do you get it
>   to be a HttpResponse? Does this depend on the ResponseHandler?

Now i have a doubt "Is HttpResponse a String ?"

Please help me clear my this doubt and explain me what was wrong in my concept.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html

Comment: thanks for replying Dr.nik .I have seen that link but was unable to clear my doubt.can you please explain me is response a string ?

Comment: do you like to discuss on HttpResponce 's type or like to solution of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*That comment on your answer makes no sense at all to me. I also have no idea why you were down-voted, though really I don't think the question was worded well enough to be properly answered, but if you're really in doubt with something like this you can think through it logically by checking the docs.*

**Short answer:**

HttpResponse is not a String.

**Long answer:**

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest%29) for `HttpClient.execute(string)` shows this as the method signature:

```
public abstract HttpResponse execute (HttpUriRequest request)
```

So clearly `execute` returns you an `HttpResponse`.

Now if you go to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html) for `HttpResponse` you find that `HttpResponse` is an interface and includes methods such as the method you used in your answer: `getStatusLine()`. Immediately you know that an interface isn't a String, so `HttpResponse` isn't a `String`, but in case you might think it's the other way and maybe `String` implements `HttpResponse`, it should be fairly obvious that `String` doesn't have a method called `getStatusLine()` and that it'd be ridiculous for something as generic as a `String` to implement an interface to do with HTTP. If you *really* want to be sure, you can check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) again and see that `String` doesn't have `getStatusLine()` and doesn't implement the interface `HttpResponse`.

Comment: The documentation also shows that `execute` has also a generic method, that depends on the `responseHandler`. `public abstract T execute` So both answers are valid. If you supply a responsehandler, it gives you a different kind of response.

Comment: That method signature: `public abstract T execute (HttpUriRequest request, ResponseHandler<? extends T> responseHandler)`

Comment: Ahhh... totally missed that Peterdk, thanks for clarifying. That said, the original question mentioned (as well as Shruti's response) happened to use the overload that only returned an HttpResponse.